# can someone please explain this: whats the emailindex over here?

Tags: python-3.x, list, automation, coursera-api

```
email_key = ' ' + 'Email Address'
email_index = user_data_list[0].index(email_key)
```

normally we take .index of the given list but here index0 is also included of another list afterwards .index(email_key) is there.its a question from coursers qwiklabs

Comment: Hi Nida, this is quite common actually.  it suggests that it might be a list of lists (or similar)....   so element 0 of the first list is another list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to **understand the structure** of the data, which is what leads to the error...

Basically, this can be the case where there is a `lists of lists` (or at least the first index `[0]` of the list is an list itself).

Here is an example of how this would work:

```py
# imagine a list that look like this...
user_data_list = [
    ['hello Email Address','world Email Address', ' Email Address'], 
    200, 
    300, 
    True, 
    3.14159
    ]

# this was the code in the original question
email_key = ' ' + 'Email Address'
email_index = user_data_list[0].index(email_key)
print(email_index)


# for clarity (with type hinting) it looks like this
email_key = ' ' + 'Email Address'
email_index:list = user_data_list[0]
email_index.index(email_key)
print(email_index)
```

both examples would print `2` as a result.